# how to stop press enter button next move to the input box on mobile. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

The focus in the input box and press the enter button. So, move to the next input field.
how to stop press enter button next move to the input box on mobile.

**NOTE: This code support only Desktop. Not in mobile(Android)**

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert();
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="textbox" class="one" />
  <input type="textbox" />
  <input type="textbox" />
  <input type="submit" /></form>
```

CodePen url : https://codepen.io/Dhaval182/pen/BajKYJK?editors=0011

Can you please help me.

Comment: thanks for quick response. but, I want see this code support only mobile devices.

Comment: Yes,Only Mobile. 

Add value to the input If you press the Enter button then the next input should not go.

Comment: focusing same input.(Only one input box - First input)

Comment: I have no idea what you intend to do. Please elaborate on the usecase

Comment: please open codepen url. : https://codepen.io/Dhaval182/pen/BajKYJK?editors=1011
first input box add value and after press enter button.  The next input box doesn't move.

same effect not working in mobile.

Comment: It alerts a blank alert and then does nothing. What is the AIM of all this. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: if I press the enter button, let me not move to the next input.

Comment: Please check in mobile.

Comment: Ok, I did. And what do I need to see?

Comment: not working in mobile. first input add value after press enter button move to next input.

same not reflect in mobile.

Comment: Your code does not move to next field on neither desktop nor mobile when enter is pressed

Comment: Even if you press the enter button, you should focus on the first input and not cross the second input.

Comment: I still have no idea what your want to see happen

Comment: Even if you press the enter button, not go to the next input.

Comment: That is what happens now.